# Передача аргумента функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, pyqt

Имеются два файла **front.py** и **main.py**.

Как мне в файле **main.py** в функцию `arch_folder()`, которая привязана к кнопке в `__init__`, 
передать путь, получаемый в функции `browse_folder()` в переменной `directory`?
За исключением изменения области видимости.

**front.py**:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 400))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 400))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnBrowse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 91, 23))
        self.btnBrowse.setObjectName("btnBrowse")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 301, 151))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.btnArch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnArch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 180, 81, 23))
        self.btnArch.setObjectName("btnArch")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btnBrowse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать папку"))
        self.btnArch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Архивировать"))
```

**main.py**

```py
import front
import sys, os, zipfile, traceback
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, front.Ui_MainWindow):
    directory = ''

    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации дизайна
        self.btnBrowse.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)
        self.btnArch.clicked.connect(self.arch_folder)

    def browse_folder(self):
        self.listWidget.clear()  # На случай, если в списке уже есть элементы
        directory = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выберите папку")

        if directory:  # не продолжать выполнение, если пользователь не выбрал директорию
            for file_name in os.listdir(directory):  # для каждого файла в директории
                self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)  # добавить файл в listWidget
        return directory

    def arch_folder(self):
        archive = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
        dirfiles = os.listdir(self.directory)
        for file in dirfiles:
            try:
                archive.write(file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
            except:
                print(traceback.format_exc())
        archive.close()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение


if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
    main()  # то запускаем функцию main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сделали `directory = ''` - атрибутом класса `ExampleApp`.

В методах этого класса вы обращаетесь к этому объекту  так -> `self.directory`.

```
#import front
import sys, os, zipfile, traceback
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 400))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 400))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnBrowse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 91, 23))
        self.btnBrowse.setObjectName("btnBrowse")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 301, 151))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.btnArch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnArch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 180, 81, 23))
        self.btnArch.setObjectName("btnArch")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btnBrowse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать папку"))
        self.btnArch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Архивировать"))


#class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, front.Ui_MainWindow):
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    directory = ''                                                                              # !!!

    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации дизайна
        self.btnBrowse.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)
        self.btnArch.clicked.connect(self.arch_folder)

    def browse_folder(self):
        self.listWidget.clear()  # На случай, если в списке уже есть элементы
        self.directory = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выберите папку")     # self.
        print(f'def browse_folder(self): self.directory = `{self.directory}`')                  # self.

        if self.directory:  # не продолжать выполнение, если пользователь не выбрал директорию
            for file_name in os.listdir(self.directory):  # для каждого файла в директории      # self.
                self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)   # добавить файл в listWidget
#        return directory

    def arch_folder(self):
        print(f'\ndef arch_folder: self.directory = `{self.directory}`')                        # self.

        '''
        archive = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
        for file in os.listdir(self.directory):  # self.directory: #dirfiles:
            try:
                archive.write(file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
            except:
                print(traceback.format_exc())
        archive.close()
        '''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp()  
    window.show()  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо огромное